# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a dynamic form using jQuery

```
$("#AddMobile").click(function () {

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'MobileDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" id="Mobile' + counter + '"/>' +
      '<input type="button" id="DeleteMobile+' + counter + '" class="DeleteMobile"  Value="Delete"/>');
    
   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        
   counter++;
});
```

and when I click on the add button I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined"

from the console

Is it a problem with libraries? How can I know to which library a function belongs?

Comment: Why are you calling `.after()` without parameters?

Comment: `after` expects an argument: http://api.jquery.com/after/ and I'm not sure it works even then, because `newTextBoxDiv` is not added to the document yet.

Comment: I would rather use .append instead of after(), seems that the example I was following wasn't tested

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `after()` in the line

```
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

Its work properly. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to your code:

1. You don't need to do this `$(document.createElement('div'))`, you can let jQuery do it for you `$("<div>")`.
2. You probably want to use either `.after()` or `.html()`, not the way you use it now `.after().html("...")`. With `.after()` you can add the HTML after the element you have selected (in your case the newly created div). With `.html()` you modify the content within the selected element.